# C# Automatically adding ID to a phrase a user enters into a List

Tags: c#

I want users to be able to add a phrase to the PhraseManager, but make it also automatically assign an ID so they can easily do stuff with that phrase (Play over text to speech, delete, etc.)

```
private List<Phrase> phrases;

    public PhraseManager()
    {
        phrases = new List<Phrase>();
    }
    public void AddPhrase (Phrase p)
    {
        phrases.Add(p);
    }
    public Phrase[] GetPhrases()
    {
        return phrases.ToArray();
    }
    public void PlayPhrase(int id)
    {
        Phrase toBePlayed = phrases.Find(x => x.GetId() == id);
        toBePlayed.Play();
    }
    public void RemovePhrase (int id)
    {
        phrases.Remove(phrases.Find(x => x.GetId() == id));
    }
}
```

Here's my code that shows the list array

```
public void ShowPhrases(Phrase[] phrases)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("______Phrases______");
        foreach (Phrase p in phrases)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.GetId() + ") " + p.GetPhrase());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("___________________");
    }
```

I tried making a foreach loop in the ShowPhrases, but I couldn't get it to work. I feel as if I was on the right track, but obviously not. Would I need to put it inside my accusers methods instead?

Comment: " feel as if I was on the right track, but obviously not" <--- not obvious.  Please explain what's not working.

Comment: Isn't the ID just the index of the phrase in the array? So you'd need a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`?

Comment: The ID would be the index, yeah. I tried placing it in the CreatePhase, and it would work but my accessor methods wouldn't pick it up. I'll try to for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want add unique id to Phrase, consider using Guid. The id will be always unique and can be generated everywhere. For example, when you generate new GUID as id in Phrase default constructor, every single instance of Phrase will have own unique id. Something like this:

```
public class Phrase {

   public Guid _id

   public Phrase(){
       _id = Guid.NewGuid();
   }

   public Guid GetId(){
       return _id
   }    
}
```